# Is there any way to bake texture from world space to UV?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, texture-coordinates

Hi I have a material with environment texture mapped with object space (like environment), and would like to bake it into the object UVs.

Now everything looks good in editor, I just make it look the same in Unity preferably with baked texture to improve the quality and so on. The problem is that I cannot find the way of bakeing it with the object's UVs

To be specific.
- I have an object with its own UVs
- Assigned a material with object space (environment texture mapping), which is 
  nothing to do with object UVs
- I would like to bake the material texture as it looks but onto the object UVs

Is there any way to do this?
I don't mind bake the texture into vertex color and then bake it to texture whatever again. just want to avoid to doing arrange the rendered texture to fit into UVs as it is tedious and does not always fit well. Any ideas? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well I just figured it out. You can just bake it. super easy

What I did

- Assign a material with HDRI environment texture based on object space mapping to your object.
- Unwrap your object
- go with bake and make sure bake the map you used in your shader i.e used diffuse node then bake diffuse, Emission then emit etc.

Baked image is perfectly projected on your UVs :)